# Conditional from collection on $lookup in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have four collections: a `Main` collection and three others `A`, `B` and `C`

The Main collection has a `foreignKey` field that points to a record in either `A`, `B` or `C`, depending on field `type`:

```
Main
{_id: 1, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeA"},
{_id: 2, foreignKey: 2, type: "TypeA"},
{_id: 3, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeB"},
{_id: 4, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeC"}


A
{_id: 1, otherData: "asdf"},
{_id: 2, otherData: "qwer"}

B
{_id: 1, otherData: "hello"},

C
{_id: 1, otherData: "world"}
```

I want to perform a join using `$lookup` inside an aggregation. Is there a way of making the `from` field depend on the value of `type` field?

The result in this example would be:

```
{_id: 1, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeA", rest: {_id: 1, otherData: "asdf"}},
{_id: 2, foreignKey: 2, type: "TypeA", rest: {_id: 1, otherData: "qwer"}},
{_id: 3, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeB", rest: {_id: 1, otherData: "hello"}},
{_id: 4, foreignKey: 1, type: "TypeC", rest: {_id: 1, otherData: "world"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understand well, but... do you mean this?

```js
db.Main.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "type": "TypeC"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "C",
      "localField": "foreignKey",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "output"
    }
  }
])
```

Do the `$lookup` only with the type you want instead of all types.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJJVfAP-lfd).

Without `$match` stage the output contains all types ([example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQ_0687siRj))

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. I want that, but for every type. Like to do the three matches and concatenating the results, let's say

Answer (score 0):

You can't make from in $lookup dynamic. What you can do here is to do 3 lookup stages on each collection (A,B,C) and then in next projection stage you will know from which field to take value based on your "type" property. What you can also do to ensure good performance is to create indexes in A,B, and C collection on those foreign keys.